# How to implement table with row and column

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How to implement a table like in the image? Table with Row and column? Can any tell me the refrence for iphone

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The columns are just an illusion.

This is done by subclassing UITableViewCell and designing the cell to have a UIImageView and three UILabels.

Assign the imageView and labels to properties of your subclass and you can configure it this way...

```
Object *object = [self.datasource objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.imageView.image = object.image;
cell.subCategoryLabel.text = object.subcategory;
cell.dateLabel.text = object.dateString;
cell.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", object.score];
```

or something like this.

Then the layout of the labels gives the illusion of having columns.

Comment: it specified for only one cell know,If am havin multiple values means what shud i do

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom cell exact according to your requirement. Add data dynamically by adding row and column. Read this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html documentation before implementing custom cell.